# bug in c++?-set_difference in c++ does not return std::copy

Tags: c++, stl, set-difference

I have a code like below:

```
typedef std::set<std::string> set_of_strings; 
            set_of_strings s1, s2, result1; 
    some_func()
    {
            s1.insert("1-2"); 
            s1.insert("1-1"); 
            s1.insert("3-4"); 
            s2.insert("1-2"); 
            s2.insert("1-3"); 
            s2.insert("3-4"); 

            set_of_strings::iterator s1_begin = s1.begin(); 
            set_of_strings::iterator s1_end = s1.end(); 
            set_of_strings::iterator s2_begin = s2.begin(); 
            set_of_strings::iterator s2_end = s2.end(); 
            set_of_strings::iterator result_begin = result1.begin();
            td::insert_iterator<set_of_strings> result_inserter = std::inserter(result1, result_begin); 

            set_difference(s1_begin, s1_end,s2_begin, s2_end,result_inserter); //This is the problem line
}
```

The compilation error that i get is `overloading ambiguity std::copy(....`
the problem is `set_difference` returns  like 
 `return copy(first1,last1,result);`

Please check [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/set_difference/) for the algo rithm of set_difference.

set_difference returns like :

```
copy(..)
```

if it is `std::copy` there would not be any problem.

i tried with putting my statement inside a block like below:

```
{
using namespace std;
set_difference(s1_begin, s1_end,s2_begin, s2_end,result_inserter);
}
```

but this doesn't work.
I know that the problem is with the copy function which we have written for our own purpose and its used at many places.Here i want to use `std::copy`. 
could anybody pls help.

Comment: [It compiles fine](http://ideone.com/AatQz). So the problem is in the code you didn't show. What are `set_of_strings`, `s1`, `s2`, `result1` and `td::`? What are *the complete* error messages?

Comment: Well the `set_difference` is defined in the `std` namespace and it should also use the `std::copy`. Can you compile [this code](http://codepad.org/KZZ8nBDL) - what does it show? Can you move your own `copy` in a different namespace?

Comment: Types are important in C++. Half the objects you are talking about we don't know the types of.

Comment: @ybungalobill.i had just given part of the code.the copy function is defined in our core application.I just know the problem i am facing .But i am unable to find the work around for my problem.And the type is not of much importance here as i have explained to you my problem.

Comment: I believe the set_difference should be explicit and use `std::copy`. Unlike `swap` and `operator<`, `copy` isn't supposed to be a customization point. Smells like a bug to me.

Comment: @Bo Persson.Yes this is what i think too.I still dont understand why did they use copy instead of std::copy.

Comment: @peter: "the copy function is defined in our core application" can you show the definition of it, including the enclosing namespace?

Comment: @BoPersson There's absolutely no problem with customizing `std::copy` on a user defined type, exactly the same as `std::swap`.  There is a more or less open question, however, as to whether implementations of the standard library should use simply `copy`, `swap`, etc. or `std::copy`, `std::swap`, etc.  The general recommended practice, at least in some circles, is to provide an overload in the same namespace as the class (so it will be found by ADL).  From a practical point of view, in any case, you don't want to provide one in global namespace, ever.

Comment: @JamesKanze: Incorrect. The implementation **shall not call anything found through ADL** unless it's explicitly permitted: "Unless otherwise specified, global and non-member functions in the standard library shall not use functions
from another namespace which are found through argument-dependent name lookup" [global functions]

Comment: @ybungalobill That's a very recent change; it's not in C++03 (the version most of the compilers we use implement).  It looks as if the committee did address the question.  (And that the recommended practice should be to specialize the function in `std::`, rather than to implement the function in your own namespace.)

Answer (score 4):

If you've written your own copy function that the compiler can see in the same scope as `std::copy` and it's a possible candidate, then sure that would cause an ambiguity.

There's no magic flag you can set to make it use `std::copy`, but I *think* if you put your own copy in a namespace and don't `using` that namespace, the compiler won't be able to find it and fall back to `std::copy`. That said, I don't think I can understand a case where you would want to create an alternate `copy` that works for set iterators, and if you wrote a generic one it probably shouldn't be called copy because it'll cause no end of ambiguity errors like this one.